# Title and label of charts showing in PrimeFaces 5.2 but not 5.1

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I am trying to set visiblity of legend by calling javascript function from setExtend() method of ChartModel class.

```
function extendLegend() {   
    alert("Some Hope");     
    this.cfg.legend = {             
            show: true,
            placement: 'outsideGrid'
    };
}
```

the problem is, The title of Chart & this function(extendLegend) is never being called in version 5.1 and legend is never appeared on screen.
but if I switch to version 5.2 it works simply fine.

Comment: Suspicious upvote... one of your collegues? Or a second acount by you ;-) And please post an [mcve]... HOW do you use this in the `p:chart` tag and model

Comment: @Kukeltje yeah this upvote is suspicious  :). here is the link of example :-http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/animate.xhtml

Comment: No, code should be posted in here. You might have made typos so please no links :)